# Calculating a measurement back-action matrix (partial inner product?)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, linear-algebra

Some papers I'm reading use a theorem by Neumark to calculate the measurement back-action matrix for the effect of introducing an ancilliary qubit $b$ in initial state $\psi_b$ interacting with the data qubit $a$ with hamiltonain $H_{ab}$ and performing a projective measurement on it after time $dt$. (See Appendix A of https://arxiv.org/abs/2003.10476)

The cumulative effect on the data qubit due to the time evolution and the measurement can be represented by a back-action matrix $M^{(r)}=\langle r_b|H_{ab}|\psi_b\rangle$ where $|r_b\rangle$ is the result of the measurement.

My question is how to actually calculate this? Since $H_{ab}$ belongs to the product space of $a$ and $b$, while $M$ is an operator in the Hilbert space of $a$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Formally, if you have resolutions of the qubit $a$ identity $\sum_i |i\rangle \!\langle i| = \sum_j |j\rangle \! \langle j| =  \mathbb{I}_a$, then
$$ M^{(r)} = \sum_{i,j} |i \rangle\!\langle i|M^{(r)}|j\rangle \langle j| = \sum_{i,j} \langle i|M^{(r)}|j\rangle  \; |i \rangle\! \langle j| 
 = \sum_{i,j} \langle i|\!\langle r_b|H_{ab} |j\rangle\!|\psi_b \rangle  \; |i \rangle\! \langle j|,$$
where, to be clear, I wrote $\langle i|\!\langle r_b|H_{ab} |j\rangle\!|\psi_b \rangle$ and not $\langle i|\!\langle r_b|H_{ab} |\psi_b \rangle \!|j\rangle$ to keep the standard convention that for both the ket and the bra the leftmost one always corresponds to qubit $a$. This is the same as saying you can calculate a particular matrix element $M^{(r)}_{ij}$ with the relationship
$$ \langle i|M^{(r)}|j\rangle = \langle i|\!\langle r_b|H_{ab} |j\rangle\!|\psi_b \rangle  .$$
Hopefully this equality seems plausible, since at this point both the right hand and left hand sides are just numbers, not operators.

More generally, you know that sandwiching an operator between a bra-ket gives you back a number. If, however, you don't sandwich it between a bra and ket on the full system, but instead a bra-ket on a subsystem, then you get something which effectively acts like a number on the subsystem corresponding to the bra-ket, but like an operator on the rest of the system.